# CSS Media Query is Broken

Tags: css, css-grid

The media query I have at the end of the CSS does not work:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .main-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

Once you shrink the window narrow enough, in the inspector in the browser it LOOKS like the line grid-template-columns is being read but it isn't because the grid doesn't change. Can someone more experienced than I let me know what problems they see?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;400;600&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 70px 10% 50px 10%;
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  color: #4E5060;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

header h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
  color: #A7A6AA;
}

header p {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 350px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, .5fr);
  gap: 30px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 25px 10%;
  height: 255px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  min-width: 350px;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.card:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-row: 2/4;
  border-top: 5px solid hsl(180, 62%, 55%);
}

.card:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  border-top: 5px solid hsl(0, 78%, 62%);
}

.card:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
  border-top: 5px solid hsl(34, 97%, 64%);
}

.card:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  border-top: 5px solid hsl(212, 86%, 64%);
}


.card h3 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card p {
  font-size: 14px;
}



@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  header {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .main-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 20px;
  }
  .card {
    margin-inline: initial;
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(1) {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(2) {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(3) {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(4) {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .main-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Reliable, efficient delivery<br><span class="bold">Powered by Technology</span>
  </h1>

  <p>Our Artificial Intelligence powered tools use millions of project data points 
  to ensure that your project is successful</p>
</header>

<section class="main-grid">

  <div class="card">
    <h3>Supervisor</h3>
    <p>Monitors activity to identify project roadblocks</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Team Builder</h3>
    <p>Scans our talent network to create the optimal team for your project</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Karma</h3>
    <p>Regularly evaluates our talent to ensure quality</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Calculator</h3>
    <p>Uses data from past projects to provide better delivery estimates</p>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I have edited this question to include the relevant code and remove the links to external sites/files.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your grid items are still being placed in specific rows and columns:

```
.card:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}
```

Therefore, the grid **automatically generates** these additional rows and columns even though your template did not specify them.

To fix the issue, set these values back to `auto`:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .card:nth-of-type(4) {
    grid-column: auto;
    grid-row: auto;
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;400;600&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 70px 10% 50px 10%;
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  color: #4E5060;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

header h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
  color: #A7A6AA;
}

header p {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 350px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, .5fr);
  gap: 30px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 25px 10%;
  height: 255px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  min-width: 350px;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.card:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-row: 2/4;
  border-top: 5px solid hsl(180, 62%, 55%);
}

.card:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  border-top: 5px solid hsl(0, 78%, 62%);
}

.card:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
  border-top: 5px solid hsl(34, 97%, 64%);
}

.card:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  border-top: 5px solid hsl(212, 86%, 64%);
}


.card h3 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card p {
  font-size: 14px;
}


@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  header {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .main-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 20px;
  }
  .card {
    margin-inline: initial;
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(1) {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(2) {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(3) {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(4) {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .main-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(1), .card:nth-of-type(2), .card:nth-of-type(3), .card:nth-of-type(4) {
    grid-column: auto;
    grid-row: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Reliable, efficient delivery<br><span class="bold">Powered by Technology</span>
  </h1>

  <p>Our Artificial Intelligence powered tools use millions of project data points 
  to ensure that your project is successful</p>
</header>

<section class="main-grid">

  <div class="card">
    <h3>Supervisor</h3>
    <p>Monitors activity to identify project roadblocks</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Team Builder</h3>
    <p>Scans our talent network to create the optimal team for your project</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Karma</h3>
    <p>Regularly evaluates our talent to ensure quality</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Calculator</h3>
    <p>Uses data from past projects to provide better delivery estimates</p>
  </div>

</section>
```